# Responsive design, stacking divs out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if there's a pure CSS way to stack 3 (or more) divs out of order when they get small enough to stack one on top of the other.

What I mean is, I have 3 divs in this order

```
|             |
|[1]  [2]  [3]|
|             |
```

I'd like to stack them so they are :

```
|   |
|[3]|
|[1]|
|[2]|
|   |
```

Is there any way in CSS to do this type of stacking? or will I have to use javascript for this?

Comment: The only CSS way I know of is the use of flexbox, but it comes with it's own set of browser incompatibility issues.  It'll be a little while longer before we have full flexbox support.  This all depends on your audience however.  If your audience will be using IE8 at all, then you'll need to provide a fallback or tell IE8 people to upgrade out of the prehistoric ages.

Comment: Why this order? I mean, why not just place the 3rd div on the 1st place and be done with it?

Comment: @limelights - The idea is that on desktop size screens to have a left and right sidebar.  But in mobile, the content in the right sidebar may be more important (for whatever reason) then the other two div's.  Normally, you would be forced to retain the same order you used for desktop in mobile as well.  With flexbox (or javascript for that matter) you can re-order things to make more sense when neccessary.

Comment: @limelights Two words:The Client.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, i know the "why" of the "how", but usually there's some other underlying issues when having these sorts of "requests".

Comment: @ntgCleaner  No problem m8, in regards to CSS solutions, flexbox is definitely the best way to go, but it comes with those browser issues.  Look at this article for the best info on how to use flexbox and mix the old and new syntax for th best browser support possible: http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Comment: @Michael, Great! Thank you, I will definitely take a look.  I'm not sure the client cares about IE issues that much.  or even knows!

Comment: @ntgCleaner As an experienced developer, make sure you tell your client, I can re-order this stuff using this technology... But its not supported by X...  Client needs to pick his poison.  Telling him this upfront however, will nix the likelihood of him coming back at you in the future, saying "What the hell ntgCleaner!  The site is broken!" ;)

Comment: @michael - You've got a great point.  Fortunately, the client is the company I work for and we are just putting lipstick on a pig right now to doll it up.  They understand the entire thing is broken at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float #3 (first in content order) to the right, and float #1 and #2 to the left. Remove the floats for smaller screen dimensions.

Comment: This seems much easier and simpler than my approach.

Comment: This is THE answer to this SPECIFIC stack and I thank you for that, though I'm wondering if there is a more specific way to order these items.  Steves response allows me to place the items any where in the row

Comment: Really? As far as I can tell, without using JavaScript, both of our answers depend on the content order for the final stack.

I guess if you want a solution to some variable stacking order, you'll have to ask it that way and give more than 1 example.

Comment: @RodneyGolpe, That's very true. for my original question, I'll give you the answer, though for more variable types, I would want to explore steve's answer more

Comment: Haha, give Steve the points if you're using his solution. Poor Steve!

Answer (score 2):

I like to use table groups to help me with difficult orderings that go against the flow of the document.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knbscu2k/)

**Example**

```
<ul>
    <li class="one">One</li>
    <li class="two">Two</li>
    <li class="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.two {
   display: table-footer-group;
   /* Will be displayed at the bottom */
   background-color: green;
}
.one {
  display: table-row-group;
  /* Will be displayed in the middle */
  background-color: yellow;
}
.three {
  display: table-header-group;
  /* Will be displayed at the top */
  background-color: lightblue;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  ul li {
    float: left;
  }    
}
```

Comment: The answer is TABLES courtesy of Mr. BACON. Double win.

Answer (score 1):

Although not pretty, the typical way to handle this is using negative margins. If you view the snippet below at a small screen vs a large screen, you will see the ordering that you desired. I am using negative and positive margins to move the columns around.

```css
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  
  .column-right {
    margin-left: 66.66%;
  }
  
  .column-left {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  
  .column-middle {
    margin-left: -66.66%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column column-right">3</div>
<div class="column column-left">1</div>
<div class="column column-middle">2</div>
```

Most responsive grid systems have something similar built in. For example, Bootstrap follows a similar approach in their push and pull classes using `left` and `right` properties.

Comment: Great solution Steve.  I wonder if this will impact link clicking at all?  I will definitely try this out!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this basic technique. Also try to get familiar with responsive web design.

```css
div{ 
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
#container{ 
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
#container .item{
      width:16%;
     float:left;
     padding:50px;
     position:relative;
}
/* CSS3 - change divs width on window resize  */
@media screen and (max-width: 468px){
  #container .item{ 
                  width:100%; 
               }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div class="item">
           One
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           Two
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           Three
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to make comments like "get familiar with responsive design." please provide more input. The OP is obviously aware of the subject and is seeking help. Pithy comments like this sound like an insult. For instance, what is it about responsive design that might be causing confusion here?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, Thank you - To add to that, I know how to make my items STACK and 100%.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Thank you for your suggestion. I'm new to stackoverflow. Sorry if this sound like an insult. I misread your question. I will remove my answer if not helpful.

Comment: @ChampSuperTramp, No problem - Welcome to SO